# When is the range of a bounded linear operator dense

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(X, Y)$, I'm wondering what are the necessary and sufficient conditions that the range of $T$ is dense.

Non-dense means the $\text{Ran}(T)$ is a proper linear subspace of $Y$, right?

Comment: Non-dense means that *the closure* of $\mathrm{ran}T$ is a proper subspace of $Y$. What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: I'm curious about the general approach to prove the range is dense. Like by contradiction?

Comment: The Hahn-Banach Theorem implies that $T:X\to Y$ (for locally convex spaces $X$, $Y$) has dense range if and only if the transposed map $T^t:Y'\to X'$ between the continuous duals is injective. This can be very useful in applications. For example, in Rudin's *Functional Analysis* Runge's Approximation Theorem is proved using this principle.